# What is the shortest regex I can write for inserting 3 characters into a string?

Tags: regex, string, text

I'm seeking the most efficient use of RegEx for inserting 3 characters into a string, 3 characters from the beginning.

**Match**: ABC123

**Insert**: 000

**Result**: ABC000123

My main goal is efficiency in my RegEx. So far, my economical attempts haven't produced this result.

Comment: How are you measuring efficiency?

Comment: Least amount of characters used.

Comment: Why do you care about how many characters you use?  Instead of worrying about false metrics like that, worry about what is most clear.

Comment: Is it possible to be both short and clear?

Comment: match against `^(.{3})(.*)`, replace with `$1<inserted_string>$2`. however, why  would you use regular expressions when you know the exact offset of the insertion point beforehand? better use `concat(orig.substring(0,3), <inserted_string>, orig.substring(3))` in the language of your choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this regex:

```
^(.{3})
```

Replace it with:

```
$1000
```

Don't confuse the above to `1000`. It is Group1(`$1`) followed by what you want to insert. In this case (`000`)

I don't know how to do it in objective-c, but you should be able to do that with above.

Comment: Do you need to use `${1}000` since the prepended content is comprised of digits as well?

Comment: I don't know the syntax of objective-c mate

Answer (score 0):

Here's the shortest way you can do it:

```
s/ABC123/ABC000123/
```

Without knowing what your rules are, we can only guess at what you're checking for.

We also don't know what language you're using.

Comment: I'm thinking objective-c from the ns tag.

Comment: ...and it's not that short. `s/ABC/ABC000/g` P.S. I know you are making a point.