# Deeply-nested groups in RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I was answering one question and I got a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842405/what-is-the-shortest-regex-i-can-write-for-inserting-3-characters-into-a-string/22842653?noredirect=1#comment34844294_22842653) from tenub.

The comment was:

> Do you need to use ${1}000 since the prepended content is comprised of digits as well?

So if I use this regex. (Don't look for practicality. This is intentional for this question)

```
^(((((((((((.{3})))))))))))
```

So in the string `"some string"`.Groups `$1` to `$11` contain. `"som"`.

Now If I wanted to replace the above string like some1 string, I would normall do:

```
$11 // Group 1 followed by my replace string "1"
```

But, that matches Group 11 which is also represented by `$11`.

I know about callback functions, but I need to know if there is any particular regex.

So, my questions:

1. Is there any special syntax so that there are no clashes between replace string `1` and Group11 which is represented by `$11`
2. Why is such nested groups valid in  regex. What are the test cases to use nested groups?

Comment: `($1)1` ? You can also replace on a callback rather than a string as the last parameter which is a lot more flexible. Such nested groups are valid for the same reason `{{{{{{}}}}}}` is valid JavaScript - the fact you can write useless things in a language doesn't make it useless.

Comment: I didn't say javascript is useless. Just asking what is the test case for using them. @BenjaminGruenbaum

Comment: No, JavaScript is not useless - but writing `{{{{{}}}}}` is useless :) Just like regex.

Answer (score 3):

You can prepend a `0` to the matching group to resolve the ambiguity. Accodring to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter), you can have only 1 or 2 digit back references.

```
"some string".replace(/^(((((((((((.{3})))))))))))/, '$011'); 
\\ => "som1e string"
```